# How to collect data for the rows that have been selected in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model-view-controller

I am receiving a list of data from server and has displayed that in table format using ng-repeat along with checkbox in each row. My requirement is to pass the selected rows back to server upon clicking a removeUserData button. Am facing issue to get it done, help would be appreciated.

```
<table border="2" border-color=black>
       <tr data-ng-repeat="user in users">
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>{{user.id}}</td><td>{{user.country}}</td><td>{{user.name}}</td>             
       </tr>
</table><br>
<button data-ng-click="removeUserData()" data-ng-show="users.length">Remove User</button>
```

Comment: i recommend you to use angular ui-grid to achieve this. Though there could be other ways but ui-gird is best in my opinion OR you can make use of $index in angularjs

Comment: @AshishAgrawal, did my answer work for you?

Comment: @developer033 yes.. n am now have enough reputation to accept ur ans. Accepted !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to make use of a `new` *property* in `users`, something like `removed`, then when `checkbox` is `checked` it will be `true`, otherwise `false`.

See it *working*:

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module("app", [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

  MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.removeUserData = removeUserData;

    $scope.users = [  
       {  
          "id":1,
          "country":"Italy",
          "name":"Pavarotti"
       },
       {  
          "id":2,
          "country":"French",
          "name":"Some user"
       }
    ];

    function removeUserData() {
      $scope.users = $scope.users.filter(function(user) {
        return !user.removed;
      })
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.removed">
      </td>
      <td ng-bind="user.id"></td>
      <td ng-bind="user.country"></td>
      <td ng-bind="user.name"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div ng-if="users.length">
    <hr>
    <button ng-click="removeUserData()">Remove User</button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your html

```
    <div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myCtrl'>
    <table border="2" border-color=black>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="user in users">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-change="storeIndexOfRow($index)">
            </td>
            <td>{{user.country}}</td>
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
        </tr>

        <button data-ng-click="removeUserData()" data-ng-show="users.length">Remove User</button>
```

Controller

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

angular
.module('myApp')
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope',
    function ($scope) {

        $scope.users = [
            { country: 'india', name: 'name1' },
            {country: 'india2', name: 'name2'}
        ];

        $scope.selectedIndex = [];

        $scope.storeIndexOfRow = function (val) {
            //write the logic for if checbox is checked or not
            $scope.selectedIndex.push(val);
            console.log($scope.selectedIndex);
        };

        $scope.removeUserData = function () {
            angular.forEach($scope.selectedIndex, function (v, k) {
                console.log($scope.users[v]);
            });
        };




    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the `ng-model` to store a map that will decide for each row if it should be deleted or not,

The `ng-model` will bind the checkbox value to the given expression, in our case to a map.

for more information about ng-model [see official documenation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions/)

the map will use `user.id` as a key, and will store a boolean value, based on the checkbox value.

lets call that map `shouldDeleteUserMap`.

Then we can filter your users array before sending it back to the server, based on `shouldDeleteUserMap`.

```
<table border="2" border-color=black>
       <tr data-ng-repeat="user in users">
            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model='shouldDelteUserMap[user.id]' ></td><td>{{user.id}}</td><td>{{user.country}}</td><td>{{user.name}}</td>             
       </tr>
</table><br>
<button data-ng-click="removeUserData()" data-ng-show="users.length">Remove User</button>
```

and your controller, would look a bit like this:

```
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.shouldDelteUserMap = {};
  $scope.users = [{
    id: 1,
    country: 'USA',
    name: 'john'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    country: 'Germany',
    name: 'jane'
  }];
   $scope.removeUserData = function(){
   var usersToRemove = $scope.users.filter( function(user){
     return $scope.shouldDelteUserMap[user.id];
    });
   console.log(usersToRemove); // here comes your function that calls the server
   }
});
```

and here is jsbin with an example:
http://jsbin.com/jisigiboha/edit?html,css,js,console,output